# How do I clear website cache via SFTP/SSH?

Tags: wordpress, caching, ssh, sftp

I'm connected to a Wordpress site via SFTP/SSH, is there anyway for me to clear the cache from here? I'm not sure what file or folder to be looking for or if it's even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress by default has no real cache. If you feel you have a caching-system enabled then it depends on what you are using. Is that a plugin like w3 total cache, wp rocket, wp super cache ecc... ?

Or maybe you have some server side caching system? Give us some more info and we can help you further.

If you have a plugin you may find a cache folder inside /wp-content, look there for a "%cache%" folder (where the % are wildcard, they can have the plugin prefix/suffix attached to the folder directory name)

Comment: No plugins caching from what I can tell, there was one but I deactivated it. Site is on cPanel, don't think that caches?
I inspected the wp_content folder and found this folder - https://imgur.com/a/4jtDxJV - Should I delete something inside of it?